# Coverity, Objective-C and travis-ci

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-code-analysis, coverity

Has anyone successfully had coverity run on their Objective-C project via travis-ci. I've followed the steps outlined at https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci and I've got as far as submitting the build to coverity to run analysis on the codebase, but I just get this error in my travis-ci log output:

`[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
 For more details, please look at: 
    /Users/travis/build/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/cov-int/build-log.txt
Extracting SCM data for 0 files...
Please see the log file '/Users/travis/build/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/cov-int/scm_log.txt' for warnings and SCM command issues.
Added 0 entries
[33;1mTarring Coverity Scan Analysis results...[0m
[33;1mUploading Coverity Scan Analysis results...[0m
 travis_fold:end:build_coverity
coverity_scan:end
$ travis/script.sh`

Full output for the build is available at https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/29211502/log.txt

https://github.com/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/blob/coverity_scan/.travis.yml is what my travis yml file looks like and my build simply points to https://github.com/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/blob/coverity_scan/travis/coverity.sh to build the project.

I've looked at the sample 'HelloWorld' .travis.yml file at https://github.com/daksheshvyas/MyHelloWorld/blob/master/.travis.yml & I don't believe that there are any glaring differences between the two.

Anyone any ideas on where I'm going wrong with this?

Sean

Comment: Can you post your build-log.txt?

Comment: Hi Mark - Unfortunately, this file (build-log.txt) is housed on the travis servers and I don't have any access to it.

Comment: Ok, what happends when you run cov-build locally?

Comment: Haven't done that just yet. Do you have this working on an Objective-C project locally? Will give it a try and post back my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Coverity does not currently support analysis of Objective-C directly.  Since your build consists entirely of Obj-C code, cov-build did not see any files that it could use.  If your project included standard C/C++, those bits of code would be included.

I don't know if it is supported with the Travis integration, but you can import analysis results from other tools into the Coverity platform.  That way you can manage all of the issues in one place and have comprehensive metrics.

Comment: Hi Jon. Are there any plans to have Coverity support Objective-C projects? https://communities.coverity.com/thread/2667 seems to indicate that there's some kind of bridge between clang results & importing them into a coverity format. What I'd be most interested in though would be a full coverity scan of an Objective-C project?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.coverity.com/press-releases/coverity-unveils-new-version-of-development-testing-platform/, it *appears* that coverity now supports Objective-C. Difficult to know whether it's all available via travis, but I'll give it a shot!